# Unknown column in field list - rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database

I get this error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 's.supplier' in 'field list': SELECT s.id, s.supplier, s.vendor, s.title, s.edition, CAST(SUM(l.amount) as UNSIGNED) AS amount
FROM softwares s
LEFT JOIN licenses l ON s.id=l.software_id
GROUP BY s.supplier, s.vendor, s.title, s.edition
```

however supplier is a column in the software table so i'm not sure why it's not recognising it?

Comment: Start you console (rails c) and paste the output of the `Software`

Comment: Software(id: integer, vendor: string, title: string, edition: string, description: string, productcode: string, supplier_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)

Comment: Use `supplier_id` instead of `supplier`, please paste the code which runs above query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s.supplier_id`, it should be. You have used the wrong column name.

Comment: "supplier" would be a relation in the Rails Model. In the db-query, it has to be "supplier_id"

Answer (score 0):

Use `supplier_id` instead of `supplier`

Your query should be something like following

```
SELECT s.id, s.supplier_id, s.vendor, s.title, s.edition, CAST(SUM(l.amount) as UNSIGNED) AS amount
FROM softwares s
LEFT JOIN licenses l ON s.id=l.software_id
GROUP BY s.supplier_id, s.vendor, s.title, s.edition
```